# Elastic Search Query for multiple conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to build a query in Elastic Search which has 3 sub conditions.
1. It must satisfy at-least one of list of provided values.
2. After 1, 2 must be satisfied and then 3rd condition.

(1 must be satisfied, 2 and 3 also must be satisfied but only after 1 is satisfied).
1 is a list of values, so anyone satisfying will suffice.

Please give a outline of how to frame the Elastic Search query using boolean parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you try `bool` query ?

Comment: I had done it using the minimumShouldMatch. I used bool query made first condition to should and remaining two conditions as must. And with the minimumShouldMatchParamater set to 1 which ensures that one should clause must match. And since remaining two are must clauses they must be satisfied as well.Is there any other way to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
          "must" :[{"term":{"sessionId":"-ShAwL2KlnVeo6nMMNX3ycVlc0kdikOWPC8vShyvpRpdmOQJkbBo-FiLJymsuZp36gcQs1I"}}],
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"visitorId": "b090606f-968d-fef4-33e3-3341f3a04265"}}, 
                 { "term" : {"clientIp": "192.168.8.100"}} 
              ]

           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the terms specified in the must, the documents must match the criteria
the terms specified in the should, any of the term can be matched